# Flash window frame around in the same way as SDI modal form do

Tags: delphi, winapi

i know Windows function FlashWindow and FlashWindowEx but they flash window title and button on the taskbar.

But how to programaticali flash window in the same way as is when we click on inactive window behind modal window? 
You know main window + you show some modal form and then you click on inactive main window then your modal form flash whole frame around the window.

**UPDATE**
I need standard way. I know that i can use Desktop Window Manager (DWM) APIs and draw frame self. But i try avoid this step as it need future maintenance.
And i do not want to spend time on analysing how to drawing this in "same" way as it is done automatically.

Comment: If you make your window modal using the regular mechanisms, you don't need to care about the flashing. Otherwise please explain why you can't do this the normal way. As it stands now, it sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Do you also want the flashing window stay the active window ? What do you want to accomplish with this ? Why not make it modal ?

Comment: Because i simulate modal forms. I have chains of forms. Each chain have one or more "modal" form. And when i click on inactive window from chain 1 i need to flash "modal" form from this chain. Now i use FlashWindowEx but effect is not good here. I need standard flashing here.

Comment: Why are you "simulating" modality instead of using "actual" modality?

Comment: Because i need that the user can access other forms like MDI but i do not like MDI at all and my users also. All are happy that have "modal" like form sequence (chain) and they can click on menu e.g. in main form and open other data form. And this all works very well. I only need to make cosmetic improvements by flashing window frame instead FlashWindowEx

Answer (score 2):

I see that it can be accomplished by FlashWindowEx :)

I simply omitted dwTimeout parameter in this function and i misunderstood the name
"*FLASHW_CAPTION*" it mean not only **Title** but also window **frame**.
The effect can be solved by this code:

```
Var f: TFlashWInfo;
begin
  f.cbSize:= SizeOf(TFlashWInfo);
  f.hwnd:= Handle;
  f.dwFlags:= FLASHW_CAPTION;
  f.uCount:= 8;
  f.dwTimeout:= 60;
  FlashWindowEx(f)
```

flash 8 times (this really mean 8 transit not times)
flash only with FLASHW_CAPTION in rate 60 milliseconds.